# How do I draw a rectangle every time the mouse is clicked in a certain area?

Tags: java, processing

I'm programming in Processing, and trying to get a rectangle to appear at the location of the mouse and stay there every time the mouse is clicked. However, when I run the program and click the mouse, the rectangle only stays for second, before it disappears. Is there another way to write it so that the rectangle isn't dependent on the mouse being clicked to exist?

Here is my code:

```
void setup()
{
   size(250, 350); 
}

void draw()
{
  background(255);
  fill(255);
  tileAp();
}

void tileAp()
{
  fill(0);
  if(mousePressed && mouseX <= 250 && mouseX >= 0 && mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= 250)
  {

      drawM(true);
  }
  else
  {

  }
}     
void drawM(boolean b)
{
  if(b == true)
  {  
    rect(mouseX, mouseY, 25, 25);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop calling `background(255)` in your `draw` method - this should allow the rectangles to stay.

Alternately, you can add each rectangle to a list, and then draw all of the rectangles every frame.

Comment: How do I re-draw that specific arraylist every frame?

Comment: Add points for the rectangle to your arraylist in your `drawM` method (instead of calling `rect`), and put the loop to draw the rectangles (ie, call `rect`) at the end of your `draw` method.

Comment: Thanks. The problem turned out to be similar to what you were saying with the background; I was spawning a grid over the top of all the rectangles every second.